# how to use the progress bar in the iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiprogressview

In my iPhone app I am downloading some data from an FTP server. To show the action I am using `UIActivityIndicator`. If I put `UIProgressView` there instead of `UIActivityIndicator`, it will be more appropriate. How do I use `UIProgressView` while downloading some data? Can anybody give me a tutorial link or example code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using NSURLConnection- methods? fro downloading fron ftp?

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD

Answer (score 40, accepted):

first you create IBOutlet in .h file

```
IBOutlet UIProgressView * threadProgressView;
```

Then in .m file in viewdidload first set progress to 0.0 and then call makeMyProgressMoving method

```
    threadProgressView.progress = 0.0;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

then add below method

```
- (void)makeMyProgressBarMoving {

        float actual = [threadProgressView progress];
        if (actual < 1) {
            threadProgressView.progress = actual + ((float)recievedData/(float)xpectedTotalSize);
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(makeMyProgressBarMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
        else{



        }

    }
```

also give your review for answer. is it useful to you?

Answer (score 4):

It is quite simple. You just need to set appropriate value of property `progress` of `UIProgressView`.

In delegate of `NSURLConnection` you should receive the amount of data you are waiting to download and update the `progress` during downloading. `Progress` is represented by a floating-point value between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive, where 1.0 indicates the completion of the task.

Answer (score 4):

You can display progress of progress bar with these line of code

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {
   if (file)
   { 
       [file seekToEndOfFile];
        progressView.progress = ((float)recievedData / (float) xpectedTotalSize);
   } 
     [file writeData:data];
     recievedData += data.length;
     NSLog(@"Receiving Bytes: %d", recievedData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the option is AFNetworking.
AFURLConnectionOperation also allows you to easily stream uploads and downloads, handle authentication challenges, monitor upload and download progress, and control the caching behavior or requests.

Answer (score 0):

noted:    self.progressionBalance.progress = 5.0/10.0;

you must set decimal.