# UIProgressView not updating as expected

Tags: ios, xcode, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

Following the answer outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412795/how-to-use-the-progress-bar-in-the-iphone-app), I managed to get a UIProgressView *sort-of* working but it seems to finish updating (i.e. the bar "fills up") before it should.

I tried adding some log statements to see what was going on:

```
float actual = [_progressBar progress];

if (actual < 1) {
    _progressBar.progress = actual + ((float)numberOfFIlesAlreadyDownloaded/(float)numberOfFilesToBeDownloaded);

    NSLog(@"progress = %f", _progressBar.progress);
    NSLog(@"expected = %d", numberOfFilesToBeDownloaded);
    NSLog(@"received = %d", numberOfFIlesAlreadyDownloaded);
    NSLog(@"actual = %f", actual);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(animateProgressBar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

This outputs:

```
 progress = 0.114286
 expected = 35
 received = 4
 actual = 0.000000
 progress = 0.285714
 expected = 35
 received = 6
 actual = 0.114286
 progress = 0.571429
 expected = 35
 received = 10
 actual = 0.285714
 progress = 0.857143
 expected = 35
 received = 10
 actual = 0.571429
 progress = 1.000000
 expected = 35
 received = 10
 actual = 0.857143 // this is the last output
```

This suggests that the progress is being incremented even when the files already received value is not and I don't understand why.

I've a feeling I've missed something obvious but would appreciate it if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose the 50% of files are downloaded so progress will be 0.5. Next if there is a delay in download still it adds according to     `_progressBar.progress = actual + ((float)numberOfFIlesAlreadyDownloaded/(float)numberOfFilesToBeDownloaded);`

So go through on how are you calling this function and this will solve the issue